# Drag Composable only inside given boundries with Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-desktop

so I have a black box (rectangle) inside another box (boundary) and the rectangle is set as draggable

But now I can drag the rectangle around the whole window, but I want that if the rectangle "leaves" the boundary it should disappear behind it.
Is there another modifier I can use for it?

Here a bit context:

My code looks like this:

```
MaterialTheme {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(500f.dp)
            .border(2f.dp, Color.Black, RectangleShape)
        ){
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), 0) }
                .draggable(
                    orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                        offsetX += delta
                    }
                )
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .size(100f.dp)
            ){
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
```

When I drag the rectangle outside the boundary it looks like this:

[image: Unwanted behavior]

But it should more like this:

[image: Wanted behavior]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the composable whose contents you want to clip add the `clipToBounds()` modifier.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .size(500f.dp)
    .border(2f.dp, Color.Black, RectangleShape)
    .clipToBounds()
)
```

Comment: I've tried that, but with no luck... 
I guess I have to set the bounds it should clip somehow, but have no idea how and where

Comment: Thats interesting because I tried both on a phone and in the emulator and that is what does the trick. Can you post also the parent composable of you Box? Or is that the top (outermost) composable?

Comment: Yeah the (outermost) Box composable should be the parent composable which defines the boundaries

Comment: Oh dammit I'm just stupid I put the modifier to the wrong coimposable...
Now it works
Sry and thanks :)

Comment: Thats a good thing, that means it works for you as well :)

Comment: Is there any way to show full dragged view at border of Parent view instead of clipping view?

Comment: @DeveloperSunshine What do you mean exactly? You do not mean the first screenshot that OP showed, so I assume you mean that the dragged view would show inside the parent and snapped to the border(s) instead of going outside of its parent (and getting clipped)?

Comment: Yes @Ma3x, it is the same as you assumed, The dragged view should show inside the parent and snap to the border instead of going out of the parent, but it also should not clipped as shown in the expected output.

Comment: @DeveloperSunshine Yes there are ways. It could be done by controlling the min and max offsets in the snippet that OP provided in this part `state = rememberDraggableState { delta -> offsetX += delta }`. There you would limit the offsetX (and also offsetY, if desired) in such a way that it never leaves the parent. Ask a new question about your case, since it might require getting parent boundaries in a way specific to your use-case.

Comment: Hi @Ma3x, I asked new question with my issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193259/drag-a-view-inside-parent-box-using-jetpack-compose, 
Could you please check and help me, any help would be much appreciated.