# Drag a view inside parent box using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am new to Jetpack compose, Please help me to find a solution to my problem.

I am trying to add a drag view, The drag view using jetpack is successfully implemented, but when I am dragging the view disappears or clips when the dragged view touches or the same position of the border of the parent box.

What I want - The dragged view should show inside the parent and snap to the border instead of going out of the parent, but it also should not be clipped.

[image]

What I Got - Dragged View getting clipped

Please check this video for more clarification - [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/k4ml26c45cl4b8urrt6c9/Screen-Recording-2023-09-28-at-1.27.19-PM.mov?rlkey=fql5tpuef4oygzz1ofzxzo08l&dl=0)

Already Checked and tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72650802/drag-composable-only-inside-given-boundries-with-jetpack-compose/72651257?noredirect=1#comment136084016_72651257)

My Code:

```
 Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                parentViewHeight = coordinates.size.height
                parentViewWidth = coordinates.size.width
            }
            .clipToBounds()
            .background(color = Color.Gray))
        {
            // Draggable point 1
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .offset {
                        IntOffset(
                            startPointForConnection1.x.toInt(),
                            startPointForConnection1.y.toInt()
                        )
                    }
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                            startPointForConnection1 = Offset(
                                startPointForConnection1.x + pan.x,
                                startPointForConnection1.y + pan.y
                            )
                            /*  val newOffset = Offset(
                                  startPointForConnection1.x + pan.x,
                                  startPointForConnection1.y + pan.y
                              )

                              var maxX = size.width - parentViewWidth.dp.toPx()
                              var maxY = size.height - parentViewHeight.dp.toPx()

                              if(maxX <0){
                                  maxX = newOffset.x
                              }
                              if(maxY <0){
                                  maxY = newOffset.y
                              }
                              startPointForConnection1 = Offset(
                                  newOffset.x.coerceIn(0f, maxX),
                                  newOffset.y.coerceIn(0f, maxY))*/


                        }
                    },
                shape = CircleShape,
                color = Color.Red,
            ) {
                // Content of the draggable point
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is limiting x and you can drag red circle when you assign new Offset inside pointerInput.

```
.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
        val summed = offset + dragAmount
        offset = Offset(
            x = summed.x.coerceIn(0f, parentWidthPx - circleDiameterPx),
            y = summed.y.coerceIn(0f, parentHeightPx - circleDiameterPx)
        )
    }
}
```

Full implementation with detactDragGestures and detectTransformGestures

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun BoxDragSample() {

    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
            .clipToBounds()
            .background(color = Color.Gray),
    )
    {
        val parentWidthPx = constraints.maxWidth
        val parentHeightPx = constraints.maxHeight

        val circleDiameter = 50.dp
        val circleDiameterPx = LocalDensity.current.run { circleDiameter.toPx() }

        val startX = LocalDensity.current.run { 150.dp.toPx() }
        val startY = LocalDensity.current.run { 50.dp.toPx() }

        var offset by remember {
            mutableStateOf(
                // You can change this position as required
                Offset(startX, startY)
            )
        }

        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(circleDiameter)
                .offset {
                    offset.round()
                }
                // Alternative 1
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                        val summed = offset + pan
                        offset = Offset(
                            x = summed.x.coerceIn(0f, parentWidthPx - circleDiameterPx),
                            y = summed.y.coerceIn(0f, parentHeightPx - circleDiameterPx)
                        )
                    }
                },
            // Alternative 2
//                .pointerInput(Unit) {
//                    detectDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
//                        val summed = offset + dragAmount
//                        offset = Offset(
//                            x = summed.x.coerceIn(0f, parentWidthPx - circleDiameterPx),
//                            y = summed.y.coerceIn(0f, parentHeightPx - circleDiameterPx)
//                        )
//                    }
//                }
            shape = CircleShape,
            color = Color.Red,
        ) {
            // Content of the draggable point
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thracian, It worked, You saved my day.

Comment: No problem. You can use either of them. Modifier.cliptoBounds() clips drawing anything outside of Composable in your case it might be redundant. Without clipping you can draw anything anywhere on screen  even that position is not in your Composable.